# Objective-C: Stopping AVAudio

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I have a scrollview and in each page it has different sound file that are playing when the user scrolls to that page.

Now the issue is when user scrolls without finishing the sound it doesn't stop it is still playing together with the new sound file that is present on the next page.

I tried putting `[audio stop]` on `scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` and `viewWillDisappear` but it's not working.

here's my code.

```
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sfxP1" ofType:@"wav"];
audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
audio.volume = 1.0;
self->voices = audio;
audio.numberOfLoops = 0;
if ([audio currentTime] != 0) [audio setCurrentTime:0];
[audio play];
```

Comment: Can you add some details on how/where `audio` is declared? Instance variable? Property? Are there multiple `audio` instances in the same object or just one that is re-used?

Comment: It seems you are initialising AudioPlayer each time which you should not. Make the `audio` object global and initialise it once OR stop and clear the old player before initialising new one.